# wind versus air-sea temperature plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot the wind versus air-sea temperature plot (aka U-∆T diagram) as shown in [image] (Ref: Kettle 2014). There are 3 variables: temperature difference, wind speed and turbulence intensity (TI) of the same length. I have been trying to plot it with hist3 but I think that's not the correct way. How can I plot such a diagram in MATLAB? Thanks.

Comment: This question could be improved drastically if you included the code you've written so far to do this & your results, so we can see what is wrong. Also, what test input data should answers use? (i.e., what data should an answer use to prove they've reproduced your anticipated result?) Anyhow, I don't see why [`hist3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html) doesn't work for your data-set... without seeing your code, maybe you could try the [`binScatterPlot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/binscatterplot.html) function since you have the Statistics Toolbox.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The example picture is given just for the understanding, not for the anticipated result. hist3 only created the bins based on x- and y-axis values. I am trying with scatter3 as well. Will try binscatterplot. thanks

Comment: sz=25; scatter(x,y,sz,z); %works but creates a bubble plot not the square bins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can produce a plot like this using the following code:

```
% x and y bins
xbins = -10:15;
ybins = 0:34;

% Determine the bin for each turbulence value
[~,~,x] = histcounts(tdiff,xbins); 
[~,~,y] = histcounts(wspeed,ybins);

% Create the final matrix
binned = accumarray([x,y],turb_int,[length(xbins),length(ybins)],@mean);
binned = binned(1:end-1,1:end-1);
```

Of course, you can use any function you like to group the values (`@mean`, `@median`, etc). To plot this you would use something like `imagesc`, or `pcolor`.

Comment: Thanks for your code. it shows problem in accumarray - "first input SUBS must contain positive integer subscripts".

Comment: This will occur if you have values outside of the `xbin` or `ybin` range. You should change them such that they include the entire range of your data.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had to do imagesc(flipud(binned')) though. Anyway, the actual values of TI can contain zero values. So, how will I differ the zero values for unavailable values.

Comment: *zero values from unavailable values

Comment: @MelB You could do something along the lines of setting the `'AlphaData'` parameter of the `imagesc` to 0 for unavailable data, and 1 for everything else - this will make the zero data blue (or whatever the zero colour is), and make the unavailable data invisible -- i.e. the white space in the image in your original post.

Comment: @MelB Also, by the way, you can just do `imagesc(binned); axis xy;` to counteract the fact that the data is plotted upside down by default.